# npm install changing local install path

Tags: angular, npm, nrwl-nx

I am trying to install a local library in one of my other local libraries. The package.json is:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@company/lib_name": "file:../../../dist/libs/company/lib_name",
  ...
}
```

However, upon installing I get the error:

```
npm ERR! Could not install from "..\..\..\dist\dist\libs\company\lib_name" as it does not contain a package.json file.
```

I do not understand why an extra dist directory is added in the install path when I try to install. I do the same thing in my other libraries and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded my version of npm from 6 to 7 and everything started working